# Install 4j trial version message

Tags: install4j

I tried the evaluation copy of Install4j. Here I noticed that a message, "This application is created with trial version of install4j." always comes when I start my application and after clicking on Ok the application gets launched.

Now , I would like to purchase the license copy.

I need the confirmation on the point that using the license copy the install4j.This  message box of trial version will not come ?

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a license key into install4 and recompile your project, the evaluation warning will not be displayed.